# Ajustar tamaño de tabla en Html2Pdf

Tags: php, html2pdf

Cuando genero un PDF con [Html2Pdf](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf), en un párrafo con varias líneas, no lo limita, si no que se alarga tanto la celda que se sale de la hoja:

Estilo:

```
$content .= '
<style>
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
}
table{
width:800px;
margin:20 ;
}
td{
border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
padding: 5px; 
max-width:520px;
word-wrap: break-word;
font-size: 8px;
}
img {
  width: 25%;
}
b{
margin: 8 ;
}
</style>';
```

Aquí la tabla:

```
$content .= '<tr><td>Incidencias</td> <td>' . $_POST['incidencias'] . '</td> 
</tr>';
$content .= '<tr><td>Acciones correctoras</td> <td>' . $_POST['acciones'] . 
'</td> </tr>';
```

Y adjunto ejemplo de como se genera:

[image: Ejemplo de como se genera]

Comment: El soporte de HTML y estilos de html2pdf es por software. No tienen implementada diferencia entre `width` y [`max-width`](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/blob/master/src/Parsing/Css.php#L762) y ni tan siquiera tienen soporte para propiedades como [`word-wrap`](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/blob/master/src/Parsing/Css.php).

Comment: intenta que que la hoja estilo este en el mismo donde genera las plantillas de pdf por ejemplo entre la etiqueta <style></style>  ademas si es necesario en la parte back-end  pon una consulta sql  limitado  para que salga  solo en una pagina . O donde tiene la etiqueta <td>pon el <th>

Answer (score 1):

El problema que estás sufriendo es debido a que no estás proporcionando las medidas correctas.

- Creas el documento, por defecto, con márgenes de [`5mm 5mm 5mm 8mm`](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/blob/master/src/Html2Pdf.php#L179).
- Das un ancho a la tabla de `800px`, que son `211 mm` (más ancho que un A4).
- Creas unos márgenes de `20px` adicionales a la tabla (`margin: 20;`, que son `5.3mm` más).

En la calculadora de CSS podrás ver que [se realizan diferentes conversiones entre unidades](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/blob/master/src/CssConverter.php#L50):

```
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9\.\-]+px$/isU', $css)) {
        $css = 25.4/96. * str_replace('px', '', $css);
    } /* ... */
```

Tu tabla tiene `800px` de ancho, que son `211 mm` (`25.4 / 96 * 800`). Un folio A4 tiene unas dimensiones de `210 x 297 mm`, por lo que estás diseñando una tabla que de comienzo ya ocupa más del ancho del folio, sobresaliendo aún más teniendo en cuenta los márgenes de la tabla y los propios del documento PDF.

Para solucionarlo basta con introducir las medidas correctas en `px` o, mejor aún, en `mm`:

```
table {
  width: 190mm; /* 210mm - 5mm x 2 (margen A4) - 5mm x 2 (margen tabla) */
  margin: 5mm;
}
```

Además, deberías indicar el ancho de cada celda para que el cálculo de los anchos sea coherente (y, de paso, facilitar el trabajo a Html2Pdf, ya que por defecto el ancho de un componente es el mismo que `$old`, el del padre):

```
$content .= '
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 20%;">Incidencias</td>
      <td style="width: 80%;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt risus vel nisi pharetra, quis finibus mauris porttitor. In porta porttitor condimentum. Donec quam ligula, facilisis eget odio sit amet, malesuada consequat lacus. Nunc at elit scelerisque, vehicula ante at, ullamcorper lacus. Morbi scelerisque mauris quis ligula ornare, et facilisis leo viverra. Cras sagittis, risus eu laoreet consequat, quam lacus viverra ipsum, ac viverra sem velit et justo. Praesent aliquet, nulla id posuere porta, ex sem semper ipsum, in tincidunt tellus risus nec eros. Proin pulvinar purus eget sem bibendum, rutrum tristique sapien faucibus. Sed ultricies ligula in accumsan placerat. Ut erat libero, commodo et mauris non, ullamcorper sodales dui. Praesent at risus euismod, vestibulum ante vitae, consequat dui. In non dignissim ipsum. Duis elit urna, luctus at ultrices faucibus, rutrum quis orci. Cras posuere mi at venenatis eleifend.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 20%;">Acciones correctoras</td>
      <td style="width: 80%;">
        <p>Suspendisse vitae justo lacus. Vestibulum aliquam nibh eget odio pulvinar, quis sollicitudin ligula ultricies. Phasellus mattis iaculis enim finibus cursus. Duis convallis dictum risus ac congue. Maecenas accumsan, magna quis porttitor egestas, urna ipsum porta nisl, non semper turpis nisl eu dui. Suspendisse aliquet sed sem eu dapibus. Etiam laoreet nisl tellus, blandit ultrices lectus cursus vel. Nulla pharetra tempus tellus iaculis vehicula. Vivamus neque tellus, faucibus a ligula et, egestas efficitur leo. Fusce efficitur velit nec turpis porttitor euismod. Duis quis lorem dictum, tempor est id, semper nibh. Morbi feugiat magna nec ante sagittis volutpat. Ut id vulputate nunc, sit amet ullamcorper enim. Phasellus sollicitudin arcu vel sem maximus, vel bibendum nunc sagittis. Aenean sagittis quis nisi id ornare.</p>
        <p>Donec gravida vulputate magna, quis consectetur est faucibus non. Nam tellus dolor, porta eget faucibus vel, imperdiet in ex. Donec sed elit auctor, luctus mi id, auctor dui. Nam convallis, augue sit amet malesuada consequat, nulla urna convallis lorem, sit amet dictum elit orci et eros. Pellentesque nec magna vel nisl condimentum interdum. Sed euismod gravida blandit. Duis convallis, risus sed tincidunt mollis, nisi nibh lobortis sapien, eu sodales nisl risus eu libero. Maecenas suscipit feugiat rutrum. Nullam fringilla faucibus tristique. Cras sed eleifend sapien. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Pellentesque lobortis condimentum quam. Proin sit amet tortor tincidunt, bibendum mi sit amet, ultricies magna. Nullam accumsan orci sit amet nisl maximus, a pellentesque orci vulputate.</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
';
```

Puedes ver tu problema reproducido en el siguiente repositorio GitHub:

- Repositorio: https://github.com/ojgarciab/stackoverflow-328102
- IDE GitPod (para probar el código del repositorio en línea):

  - https://gitpod.io/#https://github.com/ojgarciab/stackoverflow-328102
- [Uso del IDE GitPod](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GV0eGpO2NU).

Aquí puedes ver una muestra del resultado:

[image: Captura del resultado]

Comment: Lo he probado y funciona bien, pero en lugar del párrafo en el código, necesito poner la variable que contenga ese párrafo. Lo he probado y sigue saliéndose de la hoja.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código exacto para poder reproducirlo? Puedes clonar el repositorio y subir tu código.